# Getting a reference to image loaded inside an HTML 5 Canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am loading an image into an HTML 5 Canvas using drawImage method. How do I get a reference to that image later (maybe on some mouse-clicked event) so that I can do a transformation to the image (like rotation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a reference to the Image object you used to paint to the canvas.

Then,

1. Delete the canvas (clearRect)
2. Make the transformations using the canvas context
3. Draw the Image again
4. Go to 1 when you need to refresh the canvas

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Once it's drawn on the canvas it's just pixels.  No reference to the original source is retained by the canvas.  If you want to maintain state information you have to do that yourself.  Alternatively [use SVG](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/svg-0.html), that retains an internal DOM.